# Can I connect Nikon D90 to Samsung grand duos smartphone?

Tags: nikon-d90

Can I connect my Nikon D90 with Samsung grand duos (running Android Jellybean 4.1.2), using HELICON software remote?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the Helicon remote website it makes it pretty clear: http://www.heliconsoft.com/heliconsoft-products/helicon-remote/

It is compatible with the Nikon D90 and Android 3.1+. It sounds like you have both. It should be compatible.

Note, you do need Helicon Focus Premium license for usage with phones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setup you describe. To connect the Samsung to the Nikon, you will need an OTG connector, to setup the Samsung (micro USB) as host and the Nikon (mini USB) as the client.